# "Unexpected token {" when using npx babel-node

Tags: node.js, babeljs, babel-cli

Here is my script `test.js`:

```
import 'jsdom-global/register';
import 'canvas';
console.log('done');
```

And here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test-jsdom",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "anthony@me.com",
  "dependencies": {
    "canvas": "^1.6.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "jsdom": "^11.3.0",
    "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

When I run `npx babel-node test.js`, I encountered this error

```
/Users/antkong/test/node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js:10
const { URL } = require("whatwg-url");
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/antkong/test/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at globalJsdom (/Users/antkong/test/node_modules/jsdom-global/index.js:28:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/antkong/test/node_modules/jsdom-global/register.js:1:19)
```

And it is my `.babelrc` file

```
{
 "presets": ["env", "stage-0"]
}
```

It seems to me `babel-node` cannot handle es6 syntax in the dependent js file. I expect `babel-node` to be able to load and compile all dependency on the fly. How can I fix this problem?

**Version info:**

```
$ node --version
v4.8.6
$ npm --version
2.15.11
```

Comment: Are you running a current version of Node? The [`ncu`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) utility is handy for finding out if you can upgrade to newer versions of those packages as well.

Comment: Good question! I am running node 4.8.6

Comment: `babel-node` does not process files in `node_modules`.

Comment: Upgrading node is definitely the easier solution here. Node 4.x goes out of support in just a few more months anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should use more up to date version of node.

I use `nvm` to switch  node to  version 8.7.0 and the issue is fixed.